# Dynamics CRM + Outlook : Are emails sent via outlook instead of dynamics are always synced

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Requirement

We have a shared mailbox in outlook. All the emails that arrive in the inbox of the shared mailbox are converted in to a case in dynamics using Automatic Record Creation and Updation Rule.

The shared mailbox is created and approved as a mailbox in dynamics and the ARC rule is applied on the associated queue.

We asked the users to use dynamics to send email replies. The From is always set to the 'shared mailbox queue' in dynamics so that all the email conversation is tracked.

Problem -

However,the issue we are facing is as soon as the email gets created in dynamics.It gets linked to customers,users,contacts,queues wherever the email address match is found out of the box,which is creating a lot of confusion for the users when they reply to these emails.

Now I want to recommend the user to switch to outlook for replying to emails instead of using dynamics however i just want to know if they reply from outlook. The shared mailbox and the users mailbox both are synced with dynamics will all those emails be tracked against the case in dynamics?

I have tested the scenario where in when the email arrives in Inbox. it is tracked in dynamics and when replied to the tracked email via outlook the email gets created in dynamics as well.

Just want the community to guide if the approach to reply from outlook is correct? Or is there a scenario which i am missing out and can cause problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you confirm the following.

- Is Dynamics online?
- Is Exchange integration online?
- Is the outlook integration via Server side sync?

**For Server-side Synchronization:**

Sent Items folder is not tracked by default, administrator should be able to change Orgsettings to enable this, tracking is based on user personal preferences.

> Please note this is a global setting and enabled for all mailboxes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/track-sent-folder-items

Comment: Thank you so much for a reply. All answers are yes to the above questions. If sent items are not tracked then when i replied to a tracked incoming email from the shared mailbox, the email did get created in dynamics. how does this work?

Comment: Do you have dynamics app for outlook? If yes that is your answer. Outlook app detects the email if it is an already tracked conversation & tracks automatically.

Comment: Thank you again. 
Since this is a shared mailbox, it does not have the dynamics add-in. And users must use shared mailbox to reply to the emails. 
So I understand now, once the email arrives in inbox,it gets tracked so any reply made against the email in outlook will be tracked in dynamics but if they create a new email and send it will not be tracked in dynamics and needs to be tracked manually or via global settings which we can't do as of now